# How do I make Expandable Table like this UI in Flutter? I spent hours to find it but I can't seem to find it

Tags: flutter

[image]

[image]

I tried Expandable Table Package but it seems too complicated

Comment: You can create Custom table with ```ExpansionTile()``` widget.

Comment: Share your ListView code that you might have done so that I can help.